# Pip on only installs to python27 while i need it to install on python37

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, pip, docx

I have multiple instances of python in my computer namely `python27, python3.6 and python 3.7`.

The import module for **docx** worked daily on `python27` until suddenly it stopped working today. I tried installing the module again using `pip` in windows command line.

> It says only installed in python27 directory. But there's an
>   importError on my script.

I guess I should be high time i transferred into `python37` but I can't seem to make pip install into `python 3.7`

Can someone offer some advice as to the messy situation I'm in?
**I want to transfer to `python3` and install docx in `python3`**

Already checked modules using pip and docx is not there.

Comment: Probably easiest way to make sure `pip` gets installed to `python3.7` is to actually use `python3.7` to install `pip`. [following the documentation](http://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/) download `get-pip.py` (or `curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py`) then `python3.7 get-pip.py`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try setting your command prompt on the version of Python you want the module to install. Then, just use "pip", to install.

This is how you can do this:
Go into File Explorer (hopefully you have windows) and press and hold the shift key, then right click the folder that you want command prompt to look at. In this case, the folder with the version of Python. Then you click on the command prompt selection, and you're golden. Just use "pip install xyz" from there on. Glad to help
- BURAK ILOGLU

Comment: Um... how do i do that? or is there a google search term that you can help me out here?

Comment: Go into File Explorer (hopefully you have windows) and press and hold the shift key, then right click the folder that you want command prompt to look at. In this case, the folder with the version of Python. Then you click on the command prompt selection, and you're golden. Just use "pip install xyz" from there on. Glad to help.

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Comment: Hi @BURAKILOGLU yeap your method worked for me. Basically i think first thing, When i installed it, i didn't install it for all users, so the folder basically appeared in some deep folder within "APPDATA" 
The I also didn't add python3.7 to PATH, so pip constantly pointed to python27

Answer (score 0):

for python 3 try below given approaches.

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pip
```

this should get you pip3 and you can use pip3 to install packages specific to python3

and also

```
python3 -m pip install  <package name>
```